# Prestodb CLI mysql connector can't find databases with underscore in their name

Tags: presto

for example:

```
show tables from mysql.records_1;
```

returns:

```
 Table 
 -------
(0 rows)

Query 20151119_162735_00058_hja7s, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 2 total, 2 done (100.00%)
0:00 [0 rows, 0B] [0 rows/s, 0B/s]
```

Although records_1 exists and there are tables in it.

when running on databases without an underscore results are ok.

anyone encountered this issue? any resolution?

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **bug** I guess.

Read this github issue :
[PrestoDB #3763](https://github.com/facebook/presto/issues/3763)